# Replicate Instagram Search-Style Swiping Tabs

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying out some new things in swift. However, i'm fairly inexperienced so please bear with me if I use wrong terminology.

I'm looking to replicate Instagram's search view, as shown here:

[image]

the animation to the next table is shown here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5T8h.jpg

I'd appreciate any help y'all can offer on how to replicate this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a custom view that is not available by default in `UIKit`. However, it can be built by creating your own custom views.

You can use a `UIScrollView` with `isPagingEnabled` set to `true`. To implement the other features, you can use the `scrollViewDidScroll` method on `UIScrollViewDelegate` and the `setContentOffset` method to manipulate the scroll position in code.

Alternatively, there are some libraries on GitHub (example: [XLPagerTabStrip Library](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)) which you can include in your app. The source code is available so you can see how they implemented their views to build your own.